# Passing a Struct Array through a TableViewCell to another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I'm new to swift and I've been stuck on this for a while now I'm trying to pass a Struct Array from a tableview cell to another view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to share specific cell's data into table of other view controller, then you need to create an object of Model struct rather than its array just like below:

```
var newFeed: Model?
```

Next you can assign it value of particular cell before navigation in main did select method as below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Comment") as? Comment else {return}
    vc.newFeed = getInfo[indexPath.row]
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

It will assign that cell's data to newFeed Variable and relaod table with that data.

For any question, feel free to ask.